# Find strong deformation retract to corona/crown

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, deformation-theory, retraction

I'm looking to find the retraction ($r:X \rightarrow A$) and the deformation $H:X \times [0,1] \rightarrow X$) but I can't think of how, I'm bad thinking about functions, any help is appreciated!

[image: Sets]

Comment: Here are some guidelines for how to [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, parametrize the space $X$ using a vector function $\vec{p}(u,v,w)$ defined as
$$
\vec{p}(u,v,w)=((|v|+1+w)\cos(u),(|v|+1+w)\sin(u),v)
$$
where $v\in\Bbb R$, $w\in[0,1]$, and $u\in[0,2\pi]$.

For the retraction $r:X\to A$, just send $v$ to $0$.

Now, the deformation retraction $H:X\times I\to X$ that forms a homotopy $\operatorname{id}_X\simeq r:X\to A$ can be easily defined via straightline homotopy
$$
H(\vec{p}(u,v,w),t)=(((1-t)|v|+1+w)\cos(u),((1-t)|v|+1+w)\sin(u),(1-t)v)
$$
It's easy to check that $H(x,0)=\operatorname{id}_X$ and $H(x,1)=r$.

---

I could add the derivation of the parametric equation for $X$ if you want.....